# Allow users to view items in a SharePoint Document Library, but not open the files

Tags: security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have the requirement to allow users to view the content of a document library, including browsing through folders, but not actually open the individual files.

There doesn't appear to be a permission to restrict users from opening files, but still display them.

Naturally it is an option to create a view that doesn't have the 'open link' in it, but that doesn't stop users from manually constructing the URL. Also there are other options in the context menu that I want to be available for the individual documents.

I realise that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182814/view-item-but-dont-open-it-sharepoint) has been asked before.

Comment: I guess this (and the linked to 'similar question') was closed as 'off topic', but SharePoint is a development environment as well as an end user tool. This was a developer question (and a pretty popular one as well based on the number of views).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but maybe it will point you in the right direction and you can get it to work.

In a Team Site, there are the following Permission Levels:

> Read:  Can view pages and list items and download documents.
>
> View Only:  Can view pages, list items, and documents. Document types with server-side file handlers can be viewed in the browser but not downloaded.

The only difference between the two is that View Only has Open Items unchecked:

> Open Items  -  View the source of documents with server-side file handlers.

Unfortunately, according to my testing and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/61ecc6b0-af24-48c6-9af5-c4975baea3dc/) and [here](http://lambertqin.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E93C48B467E6B3E1!222.entry), it does not work. At least not with Office documents.

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried. It doesn't work.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, as your last sentence is right. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If users aren't allowed to access the content of the files, I see no reason why they should be shown the actual files, or indeed why the files should take up storage in the document library. Why not populate a list or, if you want it to make as file-like as possible, generate some dummy file hierarchy (containing empty files but with the original names) from the actual original files, which can be stored away safely? This could be done dynamically, or with a batch process that is running on a timer, dependent on how often the content of the folders changes.

Comment: The users need to see the info in custom columns and preferably access other functions in the context menu. Also I was hoping to do this by configuring SharePoint and not write custom code.

Comment: I don't think it can be done without code. Viewing documents is a base permission that is a prerequisite to almost any imaginable out-of-the-box permission. Your best bet is to copy the metadata columns into another list, perhaps via workflow, and give your users permission to interact with the list.

Comment: I disagree, this feature can be very handy if you want to list items and have users requesting access to a document.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this would be useful functionality - I was assuming there would be an option similar to "List Folder Contents" in NTFS permissions.

For example in my case I have a document library A with sensitive information in it which needs to be restricted to members of the IT department only. However there is a subfolder B which I need to let group Y view.

Currently if group Y has view permission on subfolder B they can access it via a link or by searching but this can be a bit tedious. There is no way for them to browse to it via library A.

However if I could grant "List Folder Contents" or an equivalent to group Y on library A, they could easily navigate to subfolder B without being able to open the contents of A.